# Prove that $\tau (x_1 x_2 ... x_k) \tau^{-1} = (\tau(x_1) \tau(x_2) ... \tau (x_k))$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

I want to prove that $\forall \tau \in S_n$ and for pairwise different $x_1,...,x_k \in [n]$ it holds true that:

$\tau (x_1 x_2 ... x_k) \tau^{-1} = (\tau(x_1) \tau(x_2) ... \tau (x_k))$

I don't quite understand the notation. I assume that $S_n$ is the symmetric group and $\tau$ is any permutation in $S_n$ and $(x_1 x_2 ... x_k)$ is a cycle of length $k$. However I don't understand what the second part of the equation: $(\tau(x_1) \tau(x_2) ... \tau (x_k))$ means.

Comment: The RHS is just a cycle, just like $(x_1x_2 \cdots x_k)$, but the first element in that notation is $\tau(x_1)$ instead of $x_1$ and so on

Comment: The second part means cycle: $(\tau(x_1) \; \tau(x_2) \; \ldots \; \tau(x_k))$

Comment: And I don't know any proof besides calculating by hand and separating in cases.

Comment: $S_n$ is the set of permutations on an ordered set of $n$ elements - if that's what you meant

Comment: @JihoonKang But how is the right hand side a cycle? How can we have permutations inside of cycle notation? (Since $\tau$ is a permutation)

Comment: @macco so for example, let's say we have a cycle of $\tau(1234)\tau ^{-1}$, and lets say our $\tau=(12)(34)$. Then in this case, $(\tau(1) \tau(2) \tau(3) \tau(4))$ is the same as $(2143)$

Comment: $\tau(x_i)\mapsto x_i\mapsto x_{i+1}\mapsto\tau(x_{i+1})$ This by the permutions $\tau^{-1}$, $(x_1\cdots x_n)$ and $\tau$ applied after each other.

Comment: Ah, so $\tau(x_i)$ means we apply the permutation on that $x$ and thus get a new $x$? I think I understand now.

Comment: It was confusing because I thought a permutation only can be applied to multiple elements, else it wouldn't be a permutation.

Comment: @macco I think you got it! You can think of a permutation as a bijective mapping. We give it an input, and out comes an output. The notation can get confusing sometimes because it describes the permutation entirely, but it's good to remember that a permutation is also a function. I remember when I studied this getting confused exactly the same way as you!

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

What is $\tau(x_1 x_2 \ldots x_k)\tau^{-1}$ applied to $\tau(x_1)$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Work an example. Suppose $\tau$ is $(12)(34)$ in cycle notation, and you want to conjugate $\sigma = (123)$. The claim is that $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1} = (214)$, applying $\tau$ "inside" $\sigma$. If you work through this example you should both understand the notation and see the proof.