# Show that $σ(1\, 2\, 3\, 4 ...... k)σ^{−1}=(σ(1)\,σ(2)…σ(k))$, where $(σ(1)\,σ(2)…σ(k))$ is another k-cycle.

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups

Let $σ∈S_n$ and $(1 2 3 4 ... k)∈S_n$ be a $k$-cycle. Show that $σ(1\,2\, 3\, 4\, ... k)σ^{−1}=(σ(1)\,σ(2)…σ(k))$, where $(σ(1)\,σ(2)…σ(k))$ is another k-cycle.

My current thought is: 
We know $σ$ and $σ^{−1}$ are $k$-cycles and $σ(σ^−1)=(1\, 2\, 3\, ... k)$. For $σ(1 \,2 \,3\,4\, ... k)σ^{−1}$, every element $n$ in $σ^{−1}$ first go to $n+1$ in  $(1 \,2\,3\, 4\, ... k)$, and then go to $σ(n+1)$. So it just looks like $(σ(1)\,σ(2)\,…\,σ(k))$. Is this proof correct and rigorous enough?

Comment: You need to prove it in general, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2443045/prove-that-tau-x-1-x-2-x-k-tau-1-taux-1-taux-2-tau-x?rq=1), and compare with other proofs of it on MSE, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1382105/what-does-it-means-to-multiply-a-permutation-by-a-cycle-pix-1-cdots-x-n-pi?rq=1).

Comment: Note that $\sigma$ is not necessary a $k$-cycle. There is a difference between $\sigma$ and the permutation $(\sigma(1) \sigma(2) ...\sigma(k))$.